# ImportError: cannot import name spider

Tags: python, scrapy, importerror, scrapy-splash

I am writing a simple web-scraping program in python and I got the program written but when I try to run it in command line(linux) by using the following command "scrapy crawl splash_spider" I get the following error message: "ImportError: cannot import name spider".

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRpjv.png)

items.py

```
import scrapy


class ScrapyJavascriptItem(scrapy.Item):
        home_team = scrapy.Field()
        away_team = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'scrapy_javascript'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['scrapy_javascript.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scrapy_javascript.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

SplashSpider.py

```
from scrapy.spiders import spider
class MySpider(Spider):
        name = 'SplashSpider' # Name of Spider
        start_urls = ['https://www.livescore.bet3000.com'] # url(s)

def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
                yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, args = {"wait" : 3})
#Scraping
def Parse(self, response):
        item = GameItem()
        for game in response.css(".tournament.filterable.table-block.status_upcomingCount.status_upcoming.status_liveoddsCount.status_liveodds.status_nextcount.status_next.kickoff"):
                # Text before home team
                item["home_team"] = game.css("td.hometeam.team.home::text").extract_first()
                # Text before away team
                item["away_team"] = game.css("td.awayteam.team.away::text").extract_first()
                yield item
```

Comment: It seems that `Spider` should have a capital s in SplashSpider.py

Comment: Try `from scrapy.spiders import Spider` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spider needs a capital *S*.  You can see that initial class [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py) in their code.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
```